# Responsive image with text over it resulting content below hover the image

Tags: html, css

I need a responsive image(not background image as i may replace the image with a slider) with text over it. The problem is that when i use absolute the content below the slider moves up on the slider on big screens. So in other words i want the responsive image and text on it to be displayed as a block as well.

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner_container"> 
        <img src="img/banner_1.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 top_banner_mobile">
        <div class="col-md-8"> 
            <div class="banner-title"><strong>WAKE UP IN BALI</strong></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner_container img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}

.banner-title{
    font-size: 8rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px gray, 1px 0 gray, -1px 0 gray ;
    margin: 60px 40px;
    display: block;
}
```

What should i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried to resolve with z-index?

Comment: How z-index would help?

Answer (score 0):

check my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sks7ypgq/)

use  `position:absolute` and `z-index`.

```
.banner-title {
    font-size: 8rem;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 1px gray, 1px 0 gray, -1px 0 gray;
    margin: 60px 40px;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Its not responsive at all and what if you add a text below the image? It will also hover the image